# C# / C++ - How to find out how many bad sectors on the hard drive?

Tags: c#, c++, hard-drive

Is there any way in which I can get information about the PC's hard-drive amount of bad sectors through C# or C++?

I tried looking in the C# `Win32_DiskDrive` class (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132(v=vs.85).aspx) but I didn't find anything related to bad sectors.

Comment: There's a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678703/check-for-bad-sectors-on-hard-disk It's about C, but I believe you can call the same things from C++ and C#.

Comment: You need S.M.A.R.T. info and it can be accessed in C# through WMI. Here is a completed class for monitoring that kind of information, including bad sectors: http://www.know24.net/blog/C+WMI+HDD+SMART+Information.aspx